# Hide shopping cart on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, ce-1.9.2.4

We are currently developing our site(community edition 1.9.2.4) and ideally would like to hide the shopping cart on the home page and various other content related pages.

I can not find a way to complete this and any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better idea.

- Login to **`admin panel`** and go to **`CMS | Pages`**.
- Open **home page** and click on **Design** tab.
- Under **`Custom Layout Update XML`**, put this code:

`<reference name="header">
    <remove name="minicart_head" />
</reference>`

- Click on Save Page button and check frontend.

**Note:** Flush Magento's cache, if required.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **`cms.xml`** file under **`app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout`** folder.
- Find:

`<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
</cms_index_index>`

and replace it with:

`<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="minicart_head" />
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>`

- Clear cache and check home page.

**Note:** You can follow similar process for other pages also.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will head back into the project later today and advise.

Answer (score 0):

In your Theme `Template/checkout/cart/minicart`

and apply this check

```
if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
    echo 'You are in Homepage!';
} else {
    echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!';
}
```